# Search for directories in batch - store whole path in a file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, dir, findstr

I would like to find a method to search for specific directories in specific path or drive and print them out to a file for further use.

For example in a structure like:

```
D:\Dir1\Dir2\Wanteddir
D:\Dir1\Dir3\Wanteddir
D:\Dir1\Dir4\Wanteddir
```

it should create a file "result.txt" with exactly the same pattern as above.

Now I created a script from scratch and some research on existing scrips.
And got this working.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "tmp_result_file=temp.txt"
set "result_file=result.txt"

if exist %tmp_result_file% del %tmp_result_file%
if exist %result_file% del %result_file%

dir d: /s > temp.txt

set /p searchdir=Please enter the directory name: 

for /f "tokens=3* delims= " %%i in ('FINDSTR /C:"\%searchdir%" %tmp_result_file%') do echo %%i >> %result_file%
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%a in ('find /C "\%searchdir%"    %result_file%') do set "amount=%%c"

echo.

Echo The list of found directories is %amount% lines long and contains     following paths.
echo.
type result.txt
```

Now the problem with this code is, that it "catches" all directories which contains the entered word. In the beginning of the directory name.

So if I enter just "Wanted" instead of "Wanteddir" the script would search for all the directories which begins with "Wanted"

For example:

```
D:\Dir1\Dir2\Wanteddir
D:\Dir1\Dir3\Wanteddir
D:\Dir1\Dir4\Wanteddir
D:\Wanted\Exampledir
D:\Dir1\Wantedtest\Exampledir
etc..
```

I would appreciate any suggestion for this problem.
Maybe you could also suggest some more reliable method to do a search like this.
The other problem is, that the "delims" is a space. So if anyone use a space in the directory name, the output will be some garbage too.

thx so far.

Comment: Unrelated to the question you are asking, but you assume that any name without an extension is always a folder, but that is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 0):

Exact match

```
dir /s /b /ad wanted
```

or

Contains wanted

```
dir /s /b /ad *wanted*
```

To put in a file on the desktop

```
dir /s /b /ad *wanted* > "%userprofile%\desktop\Results.txt"
```

Always look at `dir` and `forfiles` for doing file listings and searching.

Comment: -1, You should always test your code before you post! (I must confess, I sometimes fail to do so, and my post often suffers when I don't test). The OP explicitly says he is looking for a specific folder name, without wildcards. Your solution seems logical, but it simply does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to get a listing of all files/folders first - you can jump straight to the answer.

One might think that `dir /b /s /ad d:wantedDir` would work.

Unfortunately, if you do a DIR on a folder name without any wildcards, then the DIR command assumes you want to look within that folder, and not list that specific folder name :-(

The solution is to add the wildcard, but then pipe the result to FINDSTR to weed out the unwanted folders:

```
dir /b /s /ad d:wantedDir* | findstr /iec:"\\wanteddir" >result.txt
```

The `/I` option makes the search ignore case.

The `/E` option makes the search match only the end of each line.

The `/C` option makes the search a literal search, and allows spaces in the search.

The leading `\\` represents a single `\`, it is an odd quirk that literal FINDSTR searches sometimes require backslashes to be escaped as `\\`.